# Need help to preserve XML hard return in a tag

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm currently trying to download XML file using Powershell, there are some nodes in the file have format like below:

```
<BackendSystemSettings>
    <Backend
    a ="123" 
    b="ABC" 
    c="ABC123"/>
    <Backend
    a ="456" 
    b="DEF" 
    c="DEF456"/>
</BackendSystemSettings>
```

I want to keep that format, but when I save the xml file, all the elements in this tag are put into 1 line:

```
<BackendSystemSettings>
    <Backend a ="123" b="ABC" c="ABC123"/>
    <Backend a ="456" b="DEF" c="DEF456"/>
</BackendSystemSettings>
```

Above is just an example, in my real data, it's much longer, so when all the lines are merged into 1 lines, it will be very hard to check later on since the line is too long.

I tried to use Select-XML, PreserveWhitespace but nothing works. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define more complex rules on how the XML should be saved through the `XmlWriterSettings` class.

It is important to note that the input format is not preserved. Rather, the output is formatted according to the rules presented by that class.

In your case, the rules I used are :

- **Indent**:  Whether to indent elements
- **NewLineOnAttributes** :
  Whether to write attributes on individual lines (has no effect when Indent is false).
- **OmitXmlDeclaration**: Whether to write an XML declaration.

Check the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-6.0) to view all the rules available and what they do.

---

Now, what you want to see:

**Writing an XML with each attributes on separate lines**

```
# Note, I am purposefully using the non-desired output as an input.
$xml = [xml]@'
<BackendSystemSettings>
    <Backend a ="123" b="ABC" c="ABC123"/>
    <Backend a ="456" b="DEF" c="DEF456"/>
</BackendSystemSettings>
'@

Function  Export-XML {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($xml, $Path)
    # XMLWriter Settings ... Where the magic happen
    $settings = [system.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
    # Use the parameters you need 
    $settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $true 
    $settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true
    $settings.Indent = $true

    $writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($Path, $settings)
    $xml.Save($writer)
    $Writer.Dispose()
}

# Do whatever modifications you wish to perform... 
$xml.BackendSystemSettings.Backend[0].a = 'Modified !!!!'

# Here we call our new function to save the XML 
Export-XML -xml $xml -Path 'C:\temp\test\71376785.xml'
```

**Resulting output**

```
<BackendSystemSettings>
  <Backend
    a="Modified !!!!"
    b="ABC"
    c="ABC123" />
  <Backend
    a="456"
    b="DEF"
    c="DEF456" />
</BackendSystemSettings>
```

**References:**

[XmlWriterSettings Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm! But there is another problem, the original file has both situations, and I just want to keep it as the way it is. For example, the original file has 1 node with attributes aligned in 1 line, and 1 node with attributes aligned into multiple lines. If I use $settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true, it will also convert attributes in the first node into multiple lines.

Comment: I just notice that if a node has more than 5 attributes, it will be separated into multiple lines, while less than 5 attributes will be keep in 1 line. Do you have any way to use "if" to enable NewLineOnAttributes for only those nodes that have more than 5 attributes?

Comment: @TrietPhan Not through the writer settings. You'd need to use a XmlReader / XmlWriter and parse the xml yourself node by node. From there, you can customize how the xml should be written. It is a bit more involved though. I am signing off for the night but I'll see if I can whip out  a small working proof of concept to show this in action when I am back.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to find out the way to combine XmlReader and Writer while waiting for you. Have a good night!